# Ethernet switching increases a network’s available bandwidth.Exactly how does this occur?

Tags: networking, switch

7. Ethernet switching increases a network’s available bandwidth. Exactly how does this occur?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question

Comment: Possibly question number 7 in some homework :)

Comment: I would suggest reading on Wikipedia on network switches (which article one could find if one was first reading about Ethernet network). There is one answer, which is left for the reader to find as a homework. (Seriously, please do your own homework first, and if you can't understand the sources, point that out and ask for clarification - SU is not "get your homework done for free for you" service)

Answer (score 1):

The keyword here is **available**

If you use an Ethernet hub then only one device on the network can be active. That devices information is repeated on all ports.  Which means at most once the link speed as bandwidth.

Now if you use a switch then it will start as an hub but it will remember which MAC addres(ses) is(are) used on which ports. It then uses that information to forward information to only that port, leaving the rest of the network free (and able to communicate. hence higher total bandwidth).